# Oracle - How to convert Date represented by NUMBER(6,0) format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, oracle18c

I've got data from our third party partner and every date column is coded in this NUMBER(6,0) format:

```
118346
118347
118348
118351
119013
119035
119049
119051
118339
118353
119019
119028
119029
119031
```

None of the last 3 digits are more than 365, so I reckon `118339` must mean 2018 + 339 days, which is December 5, 2018: `'2018-12-05'`. I've never encountered this kind of format before, so I'm a bit helpless how to handle it. Is this some standardized format? Can I use some built-in convert function or should I just manually cut and convert it using some arithmetics?

I would like to sort my rows grouping by weeks, so maybe I shouldn't even convert it, but for some reason I feel converting to a date type would be more elegant. Which approach is the better?

EDIT: I've just checked my excel version of the data, and this format is in fact working as I've imagined. So the question stands.

Comment: If you are receiving data from a third-party but don't understand the format, you need to ask them for clarification. Never assume anything.

Comment: @WSC
Yeah, I understand you. Sadly the information transfer with the "database-guy" of the partner is a bit slow and I have limited time to work on this. I was thinking that maybe it's just a very popular format so there is no reason to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [Excel's 1900-based internal representation of dates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel). Assuming your interpretation is right, you can convert to a normal date with a bit of manipulation:

```
-- CTE for sample values
with your_table (num) as (
  select *
  from table(sys.odcinumberlist(118339, 118346, 118347, 118348, 118351, 119013, 119035,
    119049, 119051, 118339, 118353, 119019, 119028, 119029, 119031))
)
-- actual query
select num,
  date '1899-12-31'
    + floor(num/1000) * interval '1' year
    + mod(num, 1000) * interval '1' day  as converted
from your_table;

       NUM CONVERTED 
---------- ----------
    118339 2018-12-05
    118346 2018-12-12
    118347 2018-12-13
    118348 2018-12-14
    118351 2018-12-17
    119013 2019-01-13
    119035 2019-02-04
    119049 2019-02-18
    119051 2019-02-20
    118339 2018-12-05
    118353 2018-12-19
    119019 2019-01-19
    119028 2019-01-28
    119029 2019-01-29
    119031 2019-01-31
```

This treats the first three digits - obtained with `floor(num/1000)` - as the number of years, offset from 1900. Those are multiplied by a single year interval value, to give 118 or 199 years. Then it treats the last three digits - from `mod(num, 1000)` - as the number of days into that year, by multiplying by a single day interval. Both are then added to the fixed date 1899-12-31. (You could use 1900-01-01 instead but then you have to subtract a day at the end...)

Comment: My output is different from yours: `119019 -> 19-JAN.  -19`. Is this because the date is represented differently on my Oracle version?

Comment: Yes, I'm relying on my client's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the display here; the conversion creates an actual date, the client is deciding how to display it. You can change that session setting, or wrap it in a `to_char()` with a specific format.

Comment: You appear to have `nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-RR'` and `nls_date_language = 'Hungarian'`, I think? *8-)

Comment: Yes, must be true! :)

Comment: I'm thinking about the difference between `1899-12-31` and `1900-01-01`. Does the second one means `1900-01-01, 23:59:59`? Because `1900-01-01, 00:00:00` would seem more reasonable, thus I would need to use the `1900-01-01` version.

Comment: @MattSom - not really as you're only looking at dates, not times, in the Excel format. In Oracle terms they are 1899-12-31 00:00:00 and 1900-01-01 00:00:00. You can use the fixed base `date '1900-01-01'` if you prefer, but then the calculation would have to have an extra `- interval '1' day`. (Or subtract 1 from the `mod()` result before multiplying).

Comment: In other words... 118339 is the 339th day of 2018. But if you start from 2018-01-01 and add 339 days to that, you get day 340 if the year; so you need to go back a day to get to the right point. You can do that anywhere in the calculation, I just chose to do it for the base date...